# Property of inner product on Hilbert space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space equipped with inner product $\left< \cdot , \cdot \right>$.

Fix $u\in H$ and constant $R_0 > 0$.

Define subset $K_u(R_0)$ of $H$ by
$$K_u(R_0) =\{w \in H : \left< w,u \right> \,\geq R_0\}$$

Show that there exists a unique $w_0 \in K_u(R_0)$ such that

$$ ||w_0||= \inf_{w\in K_u(R_0)} ||w||.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a **hint**: show that $K_u(R_0)$ is both closed and convex. Then apply a result your professor proved - or is in your book - about closed and convex sets to conclude that $K_u(R_0)$ contains a unique point that is closest to the origin in $H$.